# In the UK which of the following regions should have capital letters?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

In the UK, which of the following regions, none of which have any administrative significance, should be given capital letters? I have arranged them according to my own inclinations.

**With capitals**

West Midlands,
East Anglia,
The Lake District,
Scottish Borders,
The Highlands,
The Home Counties,
The Yorkshire Dales,
The Fens,
The Broads,
The Cotswolds,
The New Forest,
The Channel Islands,
The Brecon Beacons,
North Wales

**Without capitals**

The south coast,
The west country,
The western isles,
The isles of Scilly,
The north Norfolk coast,
The north downs,
The south downs,
The East Anglian heights
The Derbyshire dales

Comment: West Midlands **does** [have administrative signifcance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Midlands_%28county%29). The North Downs and South Downs are specific proper names. How is this question anything but opinion-based, or intended to spark discussion? Please edit the question to include justification that it is not.

Comment: I disagree with @Andrew Leach.  Amongst the agencies that put these terms in print, there's a broad consensus, in line I think with Chris Harland's reply.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Your action I believe answers my question. You are saying it is 'primarily opinion based', which is what I am getting from people who have provided more specific answers. And, yes, sorry about the West Midlands.

Comment: In the UK in proper English, North,South, East and West always have capital letters.

Comment: @bamboo I've just done a search on today's edition of *The Independent*, and the only places where *west* is given a capital W is where it forms part of a proper noun e.g. *West Sussex, West Baltimore,West Riding, West End*. Otherwise where it appears in simple text it is not capitalised e.g. *southernmost of the Hebridean islands off the **west** coast of Scotland*. I am, however, interested in what you say. Is this something you were taught at school?

Comment: @WS2 - absolutely, taught at school, but by and large, you don't see it so much any more other than in serious or official stuff. We're all much more casual about this sort of thing in general.

Comment: @bamboo I was at grammar school from 1954 to 1961 and I don't remember being taught to write points of the compass is if they were proper nouns. But I suppose schools and teachers varied. At some point it clearly went out of fashion.

Comment: @WS2 - Our Sixth form English teacher would literally rap you across the knuckles for that kind of rookie mistake, when we were studying for O Level English Language and A level English Lit... but that was back in the dark ages!

Comment: @WS2 just noticed the dates you mentioned  - I'm talking about 1964/67

Comment: @bamboo My memory may be failing me, as my recollection is different to yours. I will ask among my peer group when I get a chance.

Comment: @bamboo You may be interested in [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14965/should-north-south-east-and-west-be-capitalised)

Comment: @WS2 - thanks, but is the guy who answered American? It's another country and they do things differently there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would say that where you are using "isles of Scilly", it should definitely be "Isles of Scilly" as that is a specific place name.

However, after that it is, I'll admit, a grey area.  Personally, I think that you are correct with south coast, west country, north Norfolk coast and East Anglian heights.  But I believe that western Isles would be more acceptable and think that the North and South Downs should be capitals as they are referring to actually geographical place names.  Also, Derbyshire Dales should be capital as you have for the Yorkshire Dales above.

Of course, if you use them in the manner that you have I don't think anyone can really criticise you because, as with the use of the apostrophe, English is a fluid language and changing all the times.  I think some of your places without capitals merely reflect the more modern (almost txt speak style) that is growing in the language.

Comment: Very good answer. Clearly it can largely be a matter of individual discretion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some of them show up in [a Google search for the terms](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=West%20Midlands%2C%20East%20Anglia%2C%20The%20Lake%20District%2C%20Scottish%20Borders%2C%20The%20Highlands%2C%20The%20Home%20Counties%2C%20The%20Yorkshire%20Dales%2C%20The%20Fens%2C%20The%20Broads%2C%20The%20Cotswolds%2C%20The%20New%20Forest%2C%20The%20Channel%20Islands%2C%20The%20Brecon%20Beacons%2C%20North%20Wales%20%22England%20England%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=West%20Midlands%2C%20East%20Anglia%2C%20The%20Lake%20District%2C%20Scottish%20Borders%2C%20The%20Highlands%2C%20The%20Home%20Counties%2C%20The%20Yorkshire%20Dales%2C%20The%20Fens%2C%20The%20Broads%2C%20The%20Cotswolds%2C%20The%20New%20Forest%2C%20The%20Channel%20Islands%2C%20The%20Brecon%20Beacons%2C%20North%20Wales%20%22England%20England%22%20Julian%20Barnes).

The Disability Rights UK publication *[Holidays 2012 in the British Isles: A guide for disabled people](http://issuu.com/espprojects/docs/druk-holiday_guide_2012)* uses the terms,

> #### North West England
>
> Cheshire, Cumbria, Greater Manchester, Lancashire and Merseyside.
>
> #### Yorkshire
>
> North, South and West Yorkshire and the East Riding of Yorkshire and Kingston-upon- Hull districts.
>
> ...
>
> #### South East Scotland
>
> Edinburgh, Falkirk, the Lothians and the Scottish Borders.
> ...
>
> #### South Wales
>
> The area that formed the counties of Glamorgan and Gwent including Cardiff and Swansea.
>
> #### West Midlands
>
> ...
>
> #### Northern Ireland
>
> #### Republic of Ireland
>
> #### Channel Islands
>
> #### Isle of Man

You could also look at the Wikipedia articles “[List of counties of the United Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_of_the_United_Kingdom)” & “[Regions of England](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England)”, but I guess you already have.

Comment: These places are not counties. They are regions that have no political or administrative significance, a bit like New England, the Rocky Mountains, or the great Lakes region, would have in America. My attention was drawn to the dichotomy of whether to use capitals by another OP who asked about 'east coast*. It seems clear that a lot is left to the writers discretion.